# Apache Spark with Scala Merge streaming text

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to merge streaming data

```
val contents = tweets.map(status => status.getText())
val tSender = tweets.map(status => status.getUser().getScreenName())
tSender.print() 
contents.print()
```

This codes working but I need to tSender + contents format.
I tried

```
println(tSender + contents)
```

but it doesn't work.
If anyone know about sth that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract all the fields you want together:

```
tweets.map(status => 
  s"${ status.getUser().getScreenName()} ${status.getText()}"
).print
```